# django: order_by and distinct OK; then order_by another field... HowTo?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, distinct, django-orm

I don't know how to do it... it seems simple but I was not able to do it... please give me a hint. Here is the model:

```
class PointOfInterest(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    geom = geomodels.PointField(srid=4326)
    ...

class Event(models.Model):
    venue = models.ForeignKey('PointOfInterest',related_name='events')
    start = models.DateTimeField()
    ...
```

The event table contains many event and there could be more than event in the same `PointOfInterest`. My goal is to select the first 10 events starting from today (there are obviously events in the past) near my place. For each `PointOfInterest` the new list has only one entry. So I started selecting the events:

```
from django.db.models import Max, Min
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta
from django.contrib.gis.measure import D
# this is my place...
pnt=Point(15.0,43.2)
# this is the date range...
start_date = datetime(date.today().year,date.today().month,date.today().day,0,0,0)
end_date = start_date + timedelta(days=30)
qs1 = Event.objects.filter(venue__geom__distance_lte=(pnt, D(km=10)))
qs2 = filter(start__range=(start_date, end_date))
qs2 = qs1.filter(start__range=(start_date, end_date))
```

The list now contains all the events requested but there are also more than one event for the same place... but I need only the upcoming one. The main problem is that this list could be big and my final step would be to get only the 10 upcoming events. I tried to use `distinct('venue')` but then I cannot order_by('start'). So I don't know how to proceed...

I also tried to go the other way around...

```
qs1 = PointOfInterest.objects.filter(geom__distance_lte=(pnt, D(km=10)))
qs2 = qs1.annotate(minDate=Min('events__start'))
qs3 = qs2.filter(minDate__range=(start_date, end_date))
```

This list give me all the `PointOfInterest` (129 in my case... while the previous list gave me 137 events... in fact there are 8 place with 2 events in the selected queries and I need to keep for each place only the upcoming one. Finally I'd like to `order_by('start')` and keep only few of them).

Also in this case I tried a lot but nothing worked... anyone can help?
Thanks

**EDIT**

Almost there. Following the suggestion from EvilX I changed the selection but `events__start__range=(start_date, end_date)` run on the places, so when I execute the 2 extra he suggested, I get the first event associated to each place (also if it's in the past). I had to change slightly the SQL query. The first attempt was this:

```
.extra(select={'event_pk': '
    SELECT start    
    FROM app_event_event 
    AS evt 
    WHERE evt.venue_id=app_place_pointofinterest.id AND evt.start >= \'2014/05/04\' 
    ORDER BY start 
    LIMIT 1'})
```

which works... then I tried to follow the django documentation to pass a parameter to the SQL query like this:

```
.extra(select={'event_pk': '
    SELECT start 
    FROM app_event_event 
    AS evt
    WHERE evt.venue_id=app_place_pointofinterest.id AND evt.start >= %s 
    ORDER BY start 
    LIMIT 1'}, params=['2014/05/04'])
```

But here I get an error: `StopIteration`; I tried different combination with and without the escape character but nothing worked... so I need some more advice.
Thanks

Comment: problem solved! Reading carefully the django documentation I disovered that there is a select_params (params is not) which has to be used... now the SQL query is OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use extra and two queries.

```
points = PointOfInterest.objects.filter(geom__distance_lte=(pnt, D(km=10)), events__start__range=(start_date, end_date)).extra(select={'event_pk': 'SELECT event.id FROM app name_event AS event where event.venue_pk=appname_pointofinterest.id ORDER BY start LIMIT 1'}).extra(select={'event_start': 'SELECT event.start_date FROM app name_event AS event where event.venue_pk=appname_pointofinterest.id ORDER BY start LIMIT 1'}).order_by('event_start')[:10]
ids = []
for point in points:
    ids.append(point.event_pk)
events = Event.objects.select_related('venue').filter(pk__in=ids)
```